# HashMismatch on STS.exe in STS 3-9-10 release (Windows zip)

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Tenable (nessus) has flagged STS.exe as untrusted because it is signed but it does not trust the signature.

This can be replicated by running the powershell command...

```
(get-authenticodesignature STS.exe)

SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
FCBCFD351C827DB7A966F0CB1E4A5505332C8E0F  HashMismatch                           STS.exe
```

I have checked the MD5 hash for the zip file and re-extracted so it is not being corrupted on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not sign the Windows executable within the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution yet, so this looks like a false warning from Tenable. I would recommend to contact their support for help on this.

Comment: Thanks very much Martin (and apologies for the cross post - I was not sure whether I was posting in the correct place). Note that this question was about STS 3.9.10 which **Windows** is definitely reporting as SHA1 signed by "Eclipse.org Foundation, Inc." on 15 July 2019 but the signature is invalid.  I have a funny feeling that it's Windows which might be at fault here - but I am continuing to investigate

Comment: Hmmm... That might be a very good find actually. This looks like the exe that we generate during the build might inherit a signing signature from the original Eclipse exe, but the validation might fail due to the build modifying the exe afterwards. Looks like something we should investigate, too. I will re-open https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/400 for this.